# copyDoc.saveAndClose(); Missing ) after argument list Google Sheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I do not not know coding - I'm trying to run the script below and recieve the **error Missing ) after argument lis**t on line 79 copyDoc.saveAndClose();

> Blockquote

Here is the url for the doc:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FcbVBHmCcDfjcaKXSU5UeaOD30h1d5yTyQp_s28VPzc/edit?usp=sharing

here is the script. Please advise. Sincere Thanks.

```
function myFunction() {

// rsaez@shsd.org
// Travel Request
// Get template from Google Docs and name it

    var docTemplate = "1FcbVBHmCcDfjcaKXSU5UeaOD30h1d5yTyQp_s28VPzc";

 // *** replace with your template ID ***

    var docName = "Travel_Request";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables

    var email_address = "rsaez@shsd.org, rsaez@shsd.org";
    var Building = e.values[5];
    var Request = e.values[6];
    var Total_Days = e.values[7];
    var Substitute_Needed = e.values[8];
    var Staff_Member_Type = e.values[9];
    var Coverage_Type = e.values[10];
    var Time_of_Day = e.values[11];
    var Coverage = e.values[12];
    var Request_Type = e.values[13];
    var Destination = e.values[14];
    var Purpose = e.values[15];
    var City = e.values[16];
    var State = e.values[17];
    var Purpose_is_related_to = e.values[18];
    var Registration = e.values[19];
    var Lodging = e.values[20];
    var Lodging_Cost = e.values[21];
    var Lodging_Total = e.values[22];
    var Meals = e.values[23];
    var Meals_Cost = e.values[24];
    var Meals_Total = e.values[25];
    var Mileage = e.values[26];
    var Other = e.values[27];
    var Travel_Cost = e.values[28];
    var Miscellanous = e.values[29];

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id

    var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
    .getId();

// Open the temporary document

    var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the document’s body section

    var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template

    copyBody.replaceText('keyDate',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyName',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyPosition',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyBuilding',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyRequest',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyDayT',
    copyBody.replaceText('keySubstitute',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyStaff',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyDay',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyTime',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyCoverage',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyRequest',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyDest',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyPurpose',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyCity',
    copyBody.replaceText('keySt',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyPurpRelated',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyRT',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyLND',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyLCP',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyLT',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyMND',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyMCP',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyMT',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyMLT',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyOT',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyTotalBOE',
    copyBody.replaceText('keyMisc',

// Save and close the temporary document

    copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// copyDoc.saveAndClose() (options.cand_email);                     
// Convert temporary document to PDF

    var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line,

```
    var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"
```

seems to be missing a ')' at the end. Perhaps that is the **Missing ) after argument list**.

Comment: Thank you . Unfortunately, it didn't resolve my issue.  Could it be that it in the beginning of the script, it's not finding the document?

Answer (score 0):

The `saveAndClose()` method is automatically invoked at the end of script execution, for each open `Document`. Maybe it'll help: `DocsList` is deprecated since 2013, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset. You should use `DriveApp` instead.

```
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
    .getId();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf');
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I be entering the the ID of the google doc in (docName+  and in any instance that  of .getID()  --- Thank you so much for any assistance with this.

Comment: Not sure I understood properly.. Every time you run the script a copy of your template is created with the given name (e.g. Travel_Request for Rickey Saez) and the ID of the new document is associated to the var copy_id. So each time you're handling a different ID. I also noticed that the var full_name isn't declared anywhere in your script

Comment: Hey K4ke4sh1, Full_ Name refers to the name of the doc template or the the recipient? I'm not sure. Please advise. Thank you. - Rickey

Comment: Watching the script you posted above, full_name should be the name of who submits the form. You didn't provide a link for the form, so we can't know how it looks like. However I believe it should be declared like the other variables at the script beginning (e.g. var full_name = e.values[n], where n is the index of the item response). I can't see it declared anywhere in your script.